# Error: $ is not defined (Angularjs )

Tags: angularjs, ajax

When i call submit function it calls but give error  like this , what is the error in this function .

```
Error: $ is not defined
$scope.submit@http://localhost/angularAjax/app.js:19:21
Mc/u/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:70:297
dc[c]</</</<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:140:1
Sc/this.$get</e.prototype.$eval@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:86:306
Sc/this.$get</e.prototype.$apply@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:86:412
dc[c]</</<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:140:505
pc/c/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:22:460
m@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:6:191
pc/c@https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js:22:433
```

Here is code :

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.hello = {name: "Boaz"};
        $scope.newName = "";
        /*$scope.sendPost = function() {
            var data = $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    name: $scope.newName
                })
            });
            $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.hello = data;
            })
        }   */                
         $scope.submit = function () {       
                $http({
                        method  : 'POST',
                        url     : 'pro.php',
                        data    : $.param($scope.contact), // pass in data as strings
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                                  }) .success(function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log(data);               
                });  
                }

    });
```

Angular is working , just ajax call fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.param` function you are calling inside `$scope.submit` is from jQuery. Make sure you are including a reference to jQuery in your page

Comment: I'm new in angularJS and getting $.param is not defined, Can you elaborate your solution?

Comment: Angularjs has a jQuery lite version built in.  This apparently is a function from the main jQuery library.  You have to add jQuery into the app before angulajrs.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can convert the data to json, using `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.hello = {name: "Boaz"};
        $scope.newName = "";
        /*$scope.sendPost = function() {
            var data = $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    name: $scope.newName
                })
            });
            $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.hello = data;
            })
        }   */                
         $scope.submit = function () {       
                $http({
                        method  : 'POST',
                        url     : 'pro.php',
                        data    : JSON.stringify($scope.contact), // pass in data as strings
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                                  }) .success(function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log(data);               
                });  
                }

    });
```